# Match two Linestring tables in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have two tables with linestrings, the first one represent wires and the second the infrastructure containing these wires.

While drawing the cables, it can happen that the wire's vertices do not match perfectly the infrastructure ones, it is generally a matter of a few cm.

Is there a way to update the whole wire table geometries by making that each vertex is matching the closest one from the infrastructure geometry?

EDIT :

Here is a picture to show the situation. In red is my infrastructure, in blue the wire. As we can see on the upper case the middle point of the wire is not perfectly matching the one of the infrastructure, and it should.

The case here is simple, in reality I have full networks of each. I would like to automatically update the wire geometries so that they match the infrastructures. Here I would like to find a query which would do like in the picture.
[image: Example]
I tried ST_Snap, but I cannot manage to make it work. I tried something like that, which didn't give any conclusive result :

```
UPDATE wire 
SET geom = ST_Snap(wire.geom, infra.geom, ST_Distance(wire.geom, infra.geom)*1.5) 
FROM infra
```

EDIT 2:

I must precise that unlike in my example, a wire can be passing over more than one infrastructure, so if there was a way by replacing the wire's geometry by the infrastructure one, it wouldn't work properly in my case.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing an example? Have you tried [ST_Snap](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but, you need to provide much more info on how this would work, as it would be possible to snap to two different wires, which you might not want.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I added more informations, is it enough?

Comment: How did it not work? I suspect the problem might be in ST_Distance, which returns the minimum distance, between two geometries, where you probably want the maximum distance. So, for a line string where  some of the points coincide, ST_Distance will be 0, and will have no effect. Perhaps try [ST_MaxDistance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MaxDistance.html)

Comment: It did not work by bringing the startpoint of my test wire to a very far infrastructure, adding many vertices, and not correcting the one I purposedly moved. I don't think I understand properly how the ST_Snap works. I guess the problem comes from the fact that it doesn't know to which infrastructure object refer to for the snapping.

Comment: And I added a precision in my second EDIT

Comment: IMO your second edit renders `ST_Snap` useless. rather, try getting a unique match (*KNN* with wire centroids to infrastructure lines, or with e.g. `ST_FrechetDistance`) and generate an infrastructure `ST_LineSubstring` between the start/end points of a wire via `ST_LineLocatePoint` to substitute your non-matching wires.

Comment: Frechet Distance is an interesting idea.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. However for now I am stuck since I only have access to PostGIS 2.3, and ST_FrechetDistance() is available since the 2.4.